# Angular - NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Window object

Tags: angular, object

Getting the below error

> Chrome 112.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0) FlightIndexComponent should create FAILED Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken Window object]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken Window object]: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Window object! at NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3228:1) at resolveToken (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3473:1) at tryResolveToken (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3417:1) at StaticInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3314:1) at resolveToken (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3473:1) at tryResolveToken (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3417:1) at StaticInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3314:1) at resolveNgModuleDep (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:19784:1) at NgModuleRef_.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:20473:1) at injectInjectorOnly (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1194:1) Expected undefined to be truthy. at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/flight-index/flight-index.component.spec.ts?:72:23) at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:391:1) at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:289:1) at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:390:1) Chrome 112.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 5 of 365 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 5.825 secs) Chrome 112.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0) FlightIndexComponent should create FAILED Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken Window object]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken Window object]: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Window object! at NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3228:1) at resolveToken (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3473:1) at tryResolveToken (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3417:1) at StaticInjector.get (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3314:1) at resolveToken (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3473:1) at tryResolveToken (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3417:1) at StaticInjector.get (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:3314:1) at resolveNgModuleDep (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:19784:1) at NgModuleRef_.get (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:20473:1) at injectInjectorOnly (/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:1194:1) Expected undefined to be truthy. at UserContext.<anonymous> (/src/app/flight-index/flight-index.component.spec.ts?:72:23) at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:391:1) at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:289:1)

## Window.provider.ts file

```
import {InjectionToken, FactoryProvider} from '@angular/core';
```

```
export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>('window');
```

```
const windowProvider: FactoryProvider = {provide: WINDOW,useFactory: () => window,};
```

```
export const WINDOW_PROVIDERS = [windowProvider];
```

## Window.service.ts file

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {WINDOW} from './window.provider';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WindowService {
  constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) public window: Window) {}
}
```

## spec.ts file

```
providers: [
        WINDOW_PROVIDERS, WindowService]

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FlightIndexComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    // const service: WindowService = TestBed.get(WindowService);
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `WINDOW` in your test:

```
providers:[
        {
          provide: WINDOW,
          useValue: window,
        },
]
```

Comment: i gave the above value but still the same issue i am getting 
======================================================================
 providers: [
        { provide: WINDOW, useValue: window, },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} }, { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
        { provide: APP_CONSTANT}             
      ]
    })
===========================================================
` NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Window object!`